# Auditd - auditctl rule to monitor dir only (not all sub dir and files etc..)

Tags: linux, shell, monitoring, auditd

I am trying to use **auditd** to monitor changes to a directory.
The problem is that when I setup a rule, it monitors the directory I specified, but also all the subdirectories and files underneath it, making the monitoring useless due to endless verbosity.

Here is how I setup the rule:

```
auditctl -w /home/raven/public_html -p war -k raven-pubhtmlwatch
```

When I search the logs using

```
ausearch -k raven-pubhtmlwatch
```

I get thousands of lines from the logs that list everything under `public_html`.

How can I limit the rule to changes on the directory specified only?

Comment: also asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19031898/7552

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credit goes to Steve @ redhat who answered my question on the [linux-audit](https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2013-September/msg00057.html) mailing list:

> A watch is really a syscall rule in disguise. If you place a watch on
>   a directory, auditctl will turn it into:
>
> ```
> -a exit,always -F dir=/home/raven/public_html -F perm=war -F key=raven-pubhtmlwatch
> ```
>
> The `-F` dir field is recursive. However, if you just want to watch the
>   directory entries, you can change that to `-F` path.
>
> ```
> -a exit,always -F path=/home/raven/public_html -F perm=war -F key=raven-pubhtmlwatch
> ```
>
> This is not recursive and just watches the inode that the directory
>   occupies.

I had to add the rule manually in `/etc/audit/audit.rules` then restart **auditd** with

```
/etc/init.d/auditd restart
```

now the rules are added and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.04 does not seem to behave in the same way w/r to system objects.  Try putting this watch on /etc or /usr/lib (In another post there appears to be issues trying to watch top level directories).  Then create something in one of those directories and nothing shows up in audit.log with the keyword.  This items relates to testing of PCI DSS 3.1 10.2.7.